# Avro append generic record with non-existent schema field

Tags: java, avro

I have following schema

```
{"namespace": "POS.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "POS",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "TransactionID", "type": "int"},
     {"name": "Date", "type": "long"},
     {"name": "Invoice", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "StoreId", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "StoreName", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "SalesMan", "type": "string"},
  ]
}
```

I am creating generic record in Java to append it to Avro file

```
    DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
    File avroFile = new File(avroFileName);

    DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(datumWriter);
    dataFileWriter.create(schema, avroFile);

    // Instantiating the GenericRecord class.
    GenericRecord salesRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);

    String key = "Product Name";
    Field field = schema.getField(key);
    if (field == null) {
        salesRecord.put(key, "some value");
    }

    dataFileWriter.append(salesRecord);
```

I am trying to append non-existent field with some value but getting an AvroRuntimeException.

Can we append non-existent field? If yes, what is the way to append such field using Java?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no field in schema, you can't put any key-value in genericRecord.

This is how put method works:

```
public void put(String key, Object value) {
    Field field = this.schema.getField(key);
    if(field == null) {
        throw new AvroRuntimeException("Not a valid schema field: " + key);
    } else {
        this.values[field.pos()] = value;
    }
}
```

PS. Are you sure your schema is valid? You have extra comma in line `{"name": "SalesMan", "type": "string"},`